# Wordpress plugin creating table

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

This is my first time trying to create a new table in the wordpress database, when the plugin is activated. I'm not gonna have a version validation for this, but I'll add this later on.

However, when my plugin is activated, my table is not created?

```
// Setup the database
function x_install() {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "test_data";
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    // Database query

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (

      id biging(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      finn_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      price bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
      title text

    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);

}

// Run database when the plugin is activated
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'x_install');
```

Spotting any errors here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress Codex says,

> You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you
>   must **include at least one KEY.**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins